# Correct class to use when creating a new shared drive

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a new Shared Drive using the Google PHP API.

I am using the code which is in the Google API docs (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives) but this is returning an error.

```
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php'); 

$driveMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_Drive(array(
    'name' => 'Project Resources'));
$requestId = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
$drive = $driveService->drives->create($requestId, $driveMetadata, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("Drive ID: %s\n", $drive->id);
```

This should be returning the Drive ID but instead I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_Drive' not found in /home//public_html/blocks/google-api-php-client/test.php on line 31

Is the code example in the Google Docs incorrect or am I being stupid?

Comment: How did you install the client library did you use composer?

Comment: I installed by downloading the latest release from Github and manually uploading to my server.

Comment: Thats not exactly installing it.   You should have checked the readme for instructions on how to use the library  Check my anwser

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken directly from the [Read Me](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/README.md) and will show you how to properly install the library for use.

## download the release

If you abhor using composer, you can download the package in its entirety. The [Releases](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases) page lists all stable versions. Download any file with the name google-api-php-client-[RELEASE_NAME].zip for a package including this library and its dependencies.

Uncompress the zip file you download, and include the autoloader in your project:

```
require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

For additional installation and setup instructions, see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation).

## Composer

The preferred method is via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Follow the [installation instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) if you do not already have composer installed.

Once composer is installed, execute the following command in your project root to install this library:

```
composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"
```

Finally, be sure to include the autoloader:

```
require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: I have already followed the instructions and downloaded the latest stable release. Apologies, i should have included this in my code.

Comment: Then all you need to do is check the paths again.  It cant find Google_Service_Drive_Drive which means your path is wrong in the require_once  try looking around on your server for autoload.php once you find it use that path. in your code

Comment: I have double checked my path and can confirm that the require is correct. The autoloader file is being loaded correctly. I can add a file to Drive with no problems but it won't work when creating a new shared drive.